# How to parse string at php?

Tags: php, parsing

guys.
I want to parse session at the header with php. Following sentense is what is in cookie that i already got using cURL.(CURLOPT_HEADER)

> SessionId="The part i want to parse"

but i don't know what i should use... (function or such like that.)

In the Python, i just use like this.

```
C_start = cookie.find('ASP.NET SessionId=') + 19
C_end = C_start + 24
SessionID = cookie[C_start:C_end]
```

SessionID parameter is what i want to get...
Please let me know HOW TO DO!

Comment: little research would help ... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: could you make simple example?...